# How can I clear data from multiple v-text-fields on button click?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a side panel with searching mechanism and I want to delete, or empty the existing data from each text fields and v-model on button click.

```
<search-panel :rightDrawer="rightDrawer" @cancelSearch="cancelSearch" @searchData="searchCustomers" @clearData="clearData">
    <v-layout row>
      <v-flex xs11 offset-xs1>
        <v-text-field name="input-1-3" label="Frist Name" light v-model="searchVm.contains.firstName"></v-text-field>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
    <v-layout row>
      <v-flex xs11 offset-xs1>
        <v-text-field name="input-1-3" label="Last Name" light v-model="searchVm.contains.lastName"></v-text-field>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
    <v-layout row>
      <v-flex xs11 offset-xs1>
        <v-text-field name="input-1-3" label="Application Name" light v-model="searchVm.contains.applicationName"></v-text-field>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
    <v-layout row>
      <v-flex xs11 offset-xs1>
        <v-select v-model="searchVm.contains.status"
                    :items="statuses"
                    label="Status"
                    item-text= "name"
                    item-value= "id"
                    :return-object="false"></v-select>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </search-panel>
```

---

```
clearData() {
    for (var e in this.searchVm.contains) {
      e.Value=""; //just for demonstartion
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this by looping through the keys of your object and use that keys to access the object properties in order to set them to empty strings

```
Object.keys(this.searchVm.contains).forEach(key=>{
this.searchVm.contains[key]="";
});
```